# jquery load data break modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have more and more problems :(

I try get a php table witch i use datatable.js for it to reload data without refresh page.

Data was load true jq with load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    data_th1();
    //data tablice
    function data_th1(){
        setInterval(function () {
                $('#tablica_home_1').load('ajax/data.php')
            });
    }
});
```

And data is loaded and i can refresh it with function data_th1() BUT when data was loaded i have one + button for open modal to add some coments, ehh problem was that modal after load data true jq not work?

HTML CODE WHEN DATA WAS LOAD (index.php)

```
<div id="tablica_home_1"></div>
```

SCRIPT IN INDEX.PHP FOR LOAD

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    data_th1();
    //data tablice
    function data_th1(){
        setInterval(function () {
                $('#tablica_home_1').load('ajax/data.php')
            });
    }
});
</script>
```

DATA.PHP

```
<?php
require_once("../includes/inc_files.php"); 

//tablica poziva
$sql7 = "SELECT * FROM svi_pozivi WHERE calltype='Outbound' AND status = 'NO ANSWER' OR calltype='Inbound' AND status = 'NO ANSWER' ORDER BY datum DESC";
$result7 = $database->query($sql7);
?>
<table id="example" class="display responsive-table datatable-example">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-transform: uppercase;">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Pozivatelj</th>
            <th>Primatelj</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Status poziva</th>
            <th>Komentar</th>
            <th>Obrada</th>
            <th>Funkcije</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($row7 = $database->fetch_array($result7)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row7['id']; ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php 
                if ($row7['calltype'] == 'Outbound'){
                    echo $row7['src']; 
                }
                else{
                    echo realbroj_ul($row7['src']); 
                    echo ' <a href="index.php?stranica=imenik-add&broj=realbroj_iz($row7["dst"])" alt="Dodaj u imenik"><i class="material-icons" style="margin-top: -4px;position: absolute;color: blue;margin-left: 5px;">add_circle</i>';
                }
            ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php 
                if ($row7['calltype'] == 'Outbound'){
                    echo realbroj_iz($row7['dst']);
                    echo '<a href="index.php?stranica=imenik-add&broj=realbroj_iz($row7["dst"])" alt="Dodaj u imenik"><i class="material-icons" style="margin-top: -4px;position: absolute;color: blue;margin-left: 5px;">add_circle</i>';
                }
                else{
                    echo $row7['dst']; 
                }
            ?></td>
            <td><?php echo realdatum($row7['datum']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo realstatus($row7['status']); ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php 
                //komentar
                $sql8 = "SELECT * FROM komentari WHERE call_id = '$row7[id]'";
                $result8 = $database->query($sql8);
                $row8 = $database->fetch_array($result8);

                if ($row8['id'] != ''){
                    echo $row8['komentar'];
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Nema komentara';
                    echo '<a data-toggle="modal" class="modal-trigger" data-id="'.$row7["id"].'" href="#komentarM" alt="Kreiraj Komentar"><i class="material-icons" style="margin-top: -4px;position: absolute;color: blue;margin-left: 5px;">add_circle</i>';

                }
                ?></td>
            <td><?php echo statuskomentara($row7['k_status']);?></td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

AND MODAL IN INDEX.PHP

```
<div id="komentarM" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>KOMENTAR</h4>
        <p>Dodajte svoj komentar</p>
    </div>
    <form id="koment_post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="agent" value="<?php echo $ime2; ?>">
    <input style="width=80%;" type="text" name="komentar" placeholder="Unesite Vaš komentar...">
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">SPREMI</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

ONE AGAIN: I have in data.php table with modal call a href, but when i call data.php with jq laod function modal was not work. I need to fix that modal show,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using modal with ajax load, i am searching a lot of site and this problem was not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm too late, but, just in case for you or another person who may want to know how to fix this:
The explanation for this, it's in [here](https://aiocollective.com/blog/click-doesn-t-work-after-ajax-load-jquery/)

I've used the element BODY to access my element, like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.Class',function () {});
$('body').on('click', '#Id',function () {});
```

This are a few examples, but it worked for me. I hope it'll help u.